# Help understanding bad code?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swf-decompiler

A long-long time ago I built a game in AS3. I have since grown unfamiliar with it AND lost the original .fla in a computer crash. I decompiled my .swf and sothink gave me this to work with:

_loc_7 = _loc_3 ? (JMP[_loc_4]) : (if (brain.S.mods.indexOf("B") != -1) goto 731, brain.S.HR ? (1.4) : (JMP[brain.sys2.stats.JMP]));

It is riddled with errors, like the if statement needing an identifier and a right-paren. before the goto. 
I can't seem to fix it and was hoping maybe you guys could help me figure out what I was doing?

Comment: Try Trillix, it may give more readable code. I'm disappointed with Sothink.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue couple of months ago and I tried Trillix and Sothink but with AS3 they don't work very well as they do with AS2. The decompiled code becomes gibberish and it is very difficult sometimes figuring out what these things mean. Of course there is a logic in the code, like '_loc_7' is a local variable in a function or loop...

If you find the solution to this let us know, I am very keen to know :D

Good luck,
Rob